# 'complex' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I'm trying a python implementation of a FFT.  I have been getting the above mentioned error for a while. What do i do?

```
import numpy
import cmath

def twiddle(r,s):
    x = (cmath.exp((2*cmath.pi*1j*s)/r))
    return x


def fft(signal):
    n = len(signal)
    if n==1:
        return signal
    else:
        Feven=fft([signal[k] for k in range(0,n,2)])
        Fodd=fft([signal[k] for k in range(1,n,2)])


    for l in range (n/2):
        F1 = Feven[l] + twiddle(n, -l) * Fodd[l]
        F2 = Feven[l] - twiddle(n, -l) * Fodd[l]
        return F1+F2
```

When I add print statements for Feven and Fodd, and feed in this:

```
print (fft([4.5, 3.4, 4.7, 3.8, 6.7, 8.0, 4.6, 7.8]))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FFT.py", line 41, in <module>
    print (fft([4.5, 3.4, 4.7, 3.8, 6.7, 8.0, 4.6, 7.8]))
  File "FFT.py", line 29, in fft
    Feven=fft([signal[k] for k in range(0,n,2)])
  File "FFT.py", line 34, in fft
   F1 = Feven[l] + twiddler(n, -l) * Fodd[l]
 TypeError: 'complex' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please provide it with working test data, otherwise it's just guessing in the dark.

Answer (score 5):

#### Fixing the bug

The problem is your line

```
return F1+F2
```

this causes `fft` to return immediately (with the complex number `F1 + F2`), when in fact it should be returning a list. What you meant, I presume, was something like this:

```
def fft(signal):
    n = len(signal)
    if n==1:
        return signal
    else:
        Feven=fft([signal[k] for k in range(0,n,2)])
        Fodd=fft([signal[k] for k in range(1,n,2)])
    F1 = [Feven[l] + twiddle(n, -l) * Fodd[l] for l in range (n/2)]
    F2 = [Feven[l] - twiddle(n, -l) * Fodd[l] for l in range (n/2)]
    return F1+F2
```

#### Other comments on your code

1. Instead of `[signal[k] for k in range(0,n,2)]` you can write `signal[0:n:2]` using [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/68063). And similarly, instead of `[signal[k] for k in range(1,n,2)]` you can write `signal[1:n:2]`.
2. In fact, since `n` is the length of the list `signal`, you can omit it since that's the default behaviour for slices. So you can actually write:

   ```
   Feven = fft(signal[::2])
   Fodd = fft(signal[1::2])
   ```
3. It doesn't make sense to have some of the "else" code inside the `else:` clause and some outside. Put it all in one or the other.
4. Since the `Fodd` numbers are always multiplied by the twiddle factor, why not do that once instead of twice? Perhaps like this:

   ```
   def fft(signal):
       n = len(signal)
       if n == 1:
           return signal
       feven = fft(signal[::2])
       fodd = [twiddle(n, -k) * o for k, o in enumerate(fft(signal[1::2]))]
       f1 = [e + o for e, o in zip(feven, fodd)]
       f2 = [e - o for e, o in zip(feven, fodd)]
       return f1 + f2
   ```

Comment: @HazelNcartha if it solved your problem, consider checking it as solved